# Where do I put LIMIT and OFFSET when combined with WHERE? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT
  razao_social,
  nome_fantasia,
  id,
  endereco,
  numero,
  cnpj,
  complemento,
  bairro,
  cidade,
  estado,
  tel1,
  tel2,
  email
FROM
  tbl_fornecedors
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 4
WHERE
  nome_fantasia LIKE '%example%'
ORDER BY nome_fantasia ASC;
```

And I get a `You have an error in your SQL syntax. I've also tried using just limit and comma (LIMIT 4,4).

Where do I have to put LIMIT and OFFSET when combined with WHERE and ORDER?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT razao_social, nome_fantasia, id, endereco, numero, cnpj, complemento,
bairro, cidade, estado, tel1, tel2, email 
FROM tbl_fornecedors 
WHERE nome_fantasia LIKE '%example%' 
ORDER BY nome_fantasia ASC 
LIMIT 4,4;
```